# Alfred Workflow - Searching on specified web browser in a new window with optional argument

Tags: applescript, workflow, alfred

I trying to make a workflow of my taste, but I'm having a real hard time. I'm new to programming in general, but I'm trying my best so any help would be appreciated!

Here's my Goal: I want to create a workflow that is triggered by a key word, with optional arguments, so that when there are no argument, a specific (not the default) browser to open a specific (not the homepage) URL, in a new window regardless the web browser app is running or not. When provided with an argument, I want to search for the argument. So for example, if I type "yy" , then Chrome opens Youtube in a new window, and if I type "yy alfred" then Chrome does a search on alfred on Youtube.

The first issue I ran into was that when apps are not running in the background and are activated, if I activate and specify an URL, I get 2 new windows. I looked it up and I did fix it (I think).

The real problem is that I cannot find how to retrieve? import? the argument as {query} and search for the argument. I've tried what the default web search does on alfred, but no luck at all. Here's my script :

```
on alfred_script(q)
if q is equal to "" then
    if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    run script "tell application \"Google Chrome\"
    activate
    open location \"https://www.youtube.com\"
    end tell"
    else
    set theApp to quoted form of "Google Chrome"
    do shell script "open -n -a " &theApp & " 
'https://www.youtube.com'"
    end if
else
    set query to q
    if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    run script "tell application \"Google Chrome\"
    activate
    open location \"https://www.youtube.com/search?q={query}\"
    end tell"
    else
    set theApp to quoted form of "Google Chrome"
    do shell script "open -n -a " &theApp & " 'https://youtube.com/search?q={query}'"
    end if
end if
end alfred_script
```

Any ideas on how I can improve my script? Thanks!

Comment: This looks like you're using _Alfred's_ **Run NSAppleScript** action, when you really ought to use **Run Script**, which you can then set to use AppleScript by selecting "osascript" from one of the drop down menus.  In this way, you will be able to use the `{query}` token in the way that you want to.  But, in general, don't use **Run NSAppleScript**.

Comment: Also, your AppleScript is peculiar, putting it politely.  Why do you have a `run script` command to open your URL?  Also, you're `do shell script` uses the `-n` flag, which you should remove (it doesn't do anything in this instance because _Chrome_ isn't running; but if it were running, the `-n` flag launches a _new_ instance of _Chrome_, which is not what you want).  I don't have the content to provide a full answer to your question, but if you like, I can provide an edit to your question to show you how to make your existing script more kosher?